# How to support multiple simultaneous BLE connections with Notify support with Bluez as peripheral

Tags: linux, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez, gatt

I would like to support multiple (at least 2) simultaneous BLE connections to Bluez as peripheral with one adapter. I believe it is technically possible since many embedded platforms support this (Silabs, Nordic).

Currently, with the first connection GATT advertisement stops altogether until the connection is dropped again. ***Is there some way to keep advertising?***

Furthermore, if this is even possible, I currently don't see a way to use attribute notifications to a specific connection. One uses the dbus PropertyChanged method for emitting characteristic value notifications, though it seems as if there is no way to specify to which remote devices to send it to. ***Is there a way to notify only a specific connection of Value changes?***

I can do the above on a Silabs EFR32 without issue but would like to get the same on embedded Linux.

Thank you kindly

Comment: This question (https://marc.info/?l=linux-bluetooth&m=157496569911675&w=2) got asked on the BlueZ developer mailing list (http://www.bluez.org/development/lists/) and didn't get an answer.

Comment: thanks @ukBaz I tried looking there, must have had the wrong search terms. I find it hard to believe that it hasn't been done before, or that there isn't a need for it yet.

Comment: @Climax Just wondering if you ever found a solution to the problem of notifying only a single connection in BlueZ?

Comment: @JasonWright unfortunately not hey. One clue might be to use the bluez fd interface where connections create file descriptors. I haven't been able to test as we migrated to Nordic hardware based system.